# Python does not execute a script installed with pip

Tags: python, ubuntu

PermissionError caused when execute [simple-websocket-server](https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server).

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/SimpleWebSocketServer/__init__.py'
```

This error does not seem like caused by some bug by the module.
So I tried add my username add to staff group then logout,
But this error does not fixed.

ls -l result:

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 root staff 37  1月 18 23:16 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/SimpleWebSocketServer/__init__.py
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.10 on Virtualbox 6.0.2
Host OS: Windows 10 1809
Python: 3.6

Comment: Looks like a problem of installation, try reinstalling with `pip install <package name> --user`

Comment: Thanks it works!
But I have not idea why this python script caused PermissionError despite I added `staff` group to my user.